# Making <table class="table"> with long horizontal rows more mobile friendly

Tags: iphone, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, mobile-website

I am using Bootstrap (2.3) on a responsive web site.

We have a lot of data tables which simply do not fit on the mobile screen horizontally, even after removing all unnecessary columns. If nothing is done, these `<table>`s cannot shrink enough, break mobile layout on iOS by expanding outside the page horizontal pages and triggering the page zoom (though no other elements on the page scale).

For now, the solution is to wrap `<table>` to overflow `<div>`

```
   <div style="overflow: auto">
        <table class="table>
        </table> 
   </div>
```

This makes the table scrollable horizontally. Applying `overflow: auto` on `<table>` itself does not seem to do anything, so the table must be wrapped. Questions

- Are there any other methods making horizontal `<table>`s mobile friendly? Some special CSS rules that could help here?
- Could `overflow: auto` applied on the `<table>` itself through CSS pseudo selectors, so that it would overflow properly?

Comment: Your best bet is to use divs.  You can't apply overflow:auto to a table object.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard [Foo Tables](http://themergency.com/footable/) are pretty good at displaying tabular information in low resolutions/responsive environments.